# Network share copy cooperation:

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have a network server which has a share that exposes a set of files. These files are consumed by processes that are running on multiple servers, sometimes several processes on the same machine.

The set of files are updated a couple times a day, and the set of files are fairly large.

We are attempting to reduce the bandwidth used by these processes retrieving these filesets by making processes that are on the same machine share the same fileset.

In order to do this, we want each process on the same machine to coordinate with the other processes that need the same files so that only one will attempt to download the files, and then the files will be shared by all the processes once complete.

Additionally, we need to prevent the server from performing an update on the fileset while a download is in progress.

In order to facilitate this requirement, I created a file lock class. This class opens a file called .lock in the specified location. The file is opened as read/write so that it will prevent another process from doing the same, regardless of what machine the process is running on. This is enclosed in a try/catch so that if the file is already locked, the exception is caught and the lock is not acquired. This already works correctly.

The problem I am trying to solve is that if a process hangs for some reason while it has the lock, all the other processes will indefinitely fail to sync these files because they cannot acquire the lock.

One solution we were exploring today was to have a multi-lock setup, where each lock would have a guid in the name, and instead of fighting over a single hard lock, locks could be acquired as many as requested. However, processes would be responsible for making sure there is only one lock set when they begin a download. This is so that if a process with a lock hangs, we can consider it expired after a certain time limit, and nothing prevents a new process from requesting a lock in addition to the hung lock.

The problem here is that the creation of these multi locks needs to be synchronized between processes or else there could be a race condition on the creation and checking of the lock count.

I don't see a way to synchronize this without reintroducing a hard locking mechanism like the first solution, but then we are right back where we started where a hung process will block the others from doing a download.

Any suggestions?

Comment: One suggestion a coworker gave me is to delay the checking of the lock count for a long period like a few seconds after creating the lock to give other processes time to resolve any ongoing lockings that they might be involved in. But this feels like a horrible dirty hack, and it certainly isn't immune to a race condition.

Answer (score 0):

A common way to tackle this is to use some sort of shareable lock file, with the real locking logic performed via the content. For example, consider an SQlite database file with a single table as a lock file: Something like

```
CREATE TABLE lock (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, 
  host TEXT,
  pid INTEGER,
  expires INTEGER
)
```

- A consumer (or the producer for an update to the fileset) requests a lock by `INSERT`ing into the table
- A process heartbeats by `UPDATE`ing its own row, making it never-expiring
- expired rows are discarded: Crashed processes will stop updating and eventually their lock will be discarded
- The lowest id holds the lock
- Processes on the same host may evaluate the `host` field to find out, if another process on the same host already wants to copy, making it obsolete to request another copy

Ofcourse this can be done via a database server (or in fact locking server) instead of a database file if feasable, but the SQlite method has the advantage of requiring nothing more than file access.

Comment: It seems like this just adds another layer of complexity to the situation. The concurrency of SQlite is handled by only one thread being able to write at a time. If that process becomes hung while it is set to write, the other processes will become stuck because they are unable to write to the lock file.

Comment: AFAIK SQlite handles broken writers gracefully - my experience says the same. It also need not be SQlite - I just default to it for cross-platform compatibility. The point is to lift the problem from something that does not share well (file) to something, that does (database)

Answer (score 0):

The trick here is good use of caching.

The designated "download" process that updates the fileset should first grab it from the remote location and store it in a temp file.  Then it should simply continue attempting to acquire a read/write lock on the local file(s) you want to replace.  When it succeeds, do the swap and drop the lock.  This part should go very very quickly.

Also, it is quite unlikely to "hang" when doing a simple file copy on a local drive.  Meaning the other dependent processes will be able to continue functioning regardless of what happens with this one.

To make sure the downloading process is functioning correctly you'll need a monitoring program that pings the download process every so often to ensure it's responsive.  If it's not then alert someone..